# deborphan packages unconfigured

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I ran this command to install deborphan:

```
apt-get install deborphan
```

Everything was downloaded, but now it can't be installed. There are a lot of packages giving errors:

```
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
procps
openssh-server
ssh
rsyslog
apport-gtk
avahi-daemon
avahi-utils
telepathy-salut
brltty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to run deborphan, it says that the file is in an inconsistent state and that there are one or more packages marked as half-installed, half-configured, etc. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: I ran what @kyodake sugested, and when i try to install deborphan now gives:

```
root@hp1-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF:~# apt-get install deborphan 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
deborphan ya está en su versión más reciente.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.
14 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se utilizarán 0 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Configurando brltty (5.2~20141018-4ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service brltty
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete brltty (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Configurando procps (1:3.3.9-1ubuntu8) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service procps
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete procps (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de udev:
 udev depende de procps; sin embargo:
 El paquete `procps' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete udev (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de systemd-services:
 systemd-services depende de udev (>= 175-0ubuntu23); sin embargo:
 El paquete `udev' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete systemd-services (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depende de systemd-services (= 204-5ubuntu20.19); sin embargo:
 El paquete `systemd-services' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libpam-No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que es un mensaje de error asociado a un fallo previo.
                                                                                                                                                                     No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                          No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                                                                                                   No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                        No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                                                                                                 No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                      systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de network-manager:
 network-manager depende de udev; sin embargo:
 El paquete `udev' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete network-manager (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de openssh-server:
 openssh-server depende de procps; sin embargo:
 El paquete `procps' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete openssh-server (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de ssh:
 ssh depende de openssh-server (>= 1:6.7p1-5ubuntu1); sin embargo:
 El paquete `openssh-server' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete ssh (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Configurando rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu14) ...
El usuario `syslog' ya es un miembro de `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete rsyslog (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de apache2:
 apache2 depende de procps; sin embargo:
 El paquete `procps' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete apache2 (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depende de procps; sin embargo:
 El paquete `procps' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete apport-gtk (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         Configurando avahi-daemon (0.6.31-4ubuntu4) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript avahi-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete avahi-daemon (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de avahi-utils:
 avahi-utils depende de avahi-daemon; sin embargo:
 El paquete `avahi-daemon' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete avahi-utils (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de telepathy-salut:
 telepathy-salut depende de avahi-daemon; sin embargo:
 El paquete `avahi-daemon' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete telepathy-salut (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: `dpkg --configure -a` failed it returned this:
`Configurando procps (1:3.3.9-1ubuntu8) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service procps
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete procps (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1`

and so on

Comment: Try the other commands.

Comment: I ran the commands and keeps failing... i updated the post